# How explicitly write a projective transformation between the conics over the univariate function field?

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, quadrics, global-fields, conic-bundles

Consider the quadratic forms
$$
Q_1 = x^2 + y^2 - (t^2+1)z^2,\qquad Q_2 = x^2 + y^2 - z^2
$$
over the rational function field $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, where $p > 2$ is a prime such that $t^2 + 1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, i.e., $p \equiv 3 \ (\mathrm{mod} \ 4)$.

These forms are isomorphic over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$, because their Hilbert symbols $(-1,t^2+1)_v$, $(-1,1)_v$ are equal for all valuations $v$ of $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$.

How explicitly write a projective transformation (over $\mathbb{F}_p(t)$) between $Q_1$ and $Q_2$? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Both conics have a rational point ($(t,1,1)$ for $Q_{1}$, $(1,0,1)$ for $Q_{2}$). Projection from this point gives an explicit isomorphism $u_{i}:Q_{i}\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$. Just take $u_{2}^{-1}\circ u_{1}$.